# Open gnome terminals programmatically with a script that requires a doublequote

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, gnome

I am trying to use a wrapper.sh script spawn separate terminals for a script that takes params in doublequotes, like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
gnome-terminal -e "./script.py -d "somevalueforscriptpy" $1"
gnome-terminal -e "./script.py -d "differentvalueforscriptpy" $1"
```

So i would want to invoke by:

```
./wrapper.sh http://goolge.com
```

but the doublequotes inside of doublequotes is causing it not to work. Im sure there is a simple solution, i just dont know it  ='(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can backslash the doublequotes

```
gnome-terminal -e "./script.py -d \"somevalueforscriptpy\" $1"
```

or, for readability, you can switch to singlequotes

```
gnome-terminal -e "./script.py -d 'somevalueforscriptpy' $1"
```